# how to fix the TS error "Property 'x' does not exist for type '{y: string; age: number; }'" when changing objects in an array using array.map

Tags: typescript

I need to add a field to the object. I use this code.

```
type DataType = {
name: string;
age: number;
}[];
const data: DataType = [
  {
  name: 'ann',
  age: 10
  },
    {
  name: 'den',
  age: 11
  },
]

type ClassatAtSchool = {
  classatAtSchool: string;
}

 const classatAtSchoolObj: ClassatAtSchool = {
  classatAtSchool: '5a',
 }

function changeData(data: DataType , additionalData: ClassatAtSchool) {
const newData = data.map((i) => {
  i.classatAtSchool = additionalData.classatAtSchool;
  return i;
})
  console.log(newData);
}

changeData(data, classatAtSchoolObj);
```

I get an error: Property 'classatAtSchool' does not exist on type '{ name: string; age: number; }'. Can you tell me how I can fix it?

You can write like this:

```
type DataType = {
name: string;
age: number;
classatAtSchool?: string;
}[];
```

I think this is the wrong approach

Thanks ).

Comment: "I think this is the wrong approach" Why? :)

Comment: In the future I may want to add a field with a different name

Comment: Should the result be `DataType[]` or something different? Because if it's `DataType` *and you need the new property*, then `DataType` needs to declare that property. If you *don't* need the property in `DataType`, then you can have a new type that includes it. But is that what should happen here?

Comment: OK. Then you add it. That is why it is called "static typing". You kinda design your types "upfront". Though it would be easier if you split your `DataType` declaration into 2: 1 for `DataTypeItem`, another for `DataTypeItem[]` if you even need to.  Also you could use intersection `DataTypeItem = {name: string; age: number;} & Partial<ClassatAtSchool>` to avoid code duplication.

Comment: VLAZ it should be a []